# Generate SSL certificates for multiple domains in SubjectAltName with Greenlock

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate, greenlock

I'm using greenlock to generate certificates, I pass it three domains, and only get 2 in my altnames:

```
const greenlock = Greenlock.create({
  agreeTos: true,
  email: myemail,
  communityMember: false,
  version: 'draft-12',
  server: 'https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory',
  configDir: '/etc/letsencrypt',
  debug: true,
  log: (debug) => { console.log(debug) },
})  
console.log({ domains })
return greenlock.register({
      domains,
      email: myemail,
      challengeType: 'dns-01',
    })
.then((result) => {
    console.log(result)
})
```

here are my logs:

```
{ domains:
 [ 'domain1',
   'domain3',
   'domain2' ] }
true
true
true
{ result:
{ 
  privkey: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n',    
  chain:  '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n',
  subject: 'domain2',
  altnames: [ 'domain1', 'domain2' ],
  _issuedAt: 2018-09-19T14:43:31.000Z,
  _expiresAt: 2018-12-18T14:43:31.000Z,
  issuedAt: 1537368211000,
  expiresAt: 1545144211000 } }
```

As you can see it's not even my first two domains that end up in my altnames but rather those that where already in the old certificate (not sure this is why tho).

I'm not married to greenlock, if someone as a better alternative I'm listening as well.

I tried passing approveDomains to my greenlock constructor and it doesn't seem to change much.
I still don't have my new domain (domain2) listed in my certificate :

```
openssl x509 -text < /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1/fullchain.pem  | grep 'DNS:' | sed 's/\s*DNS:\([a-z0-9.\-]*\)[,\s]\?/\1 /g'

domain1 domain3
```

Comment: Is `yo.panopli.shop` the domain you are missing?

Comment: nope, I'll edit to make it more clear

Comment: the domain I'm missing is domain3

Comment: How do you create the greenlock instance? Did you provide domains there? Because register() does a merge between what you give it directly  and what is already in the greenlock object.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I edited my question to answer yours.

Comment: Passing approveDomains to my greenlock constructor doesn't seem to change much.
I still don't have my new domain (domain2) listed in my certificate : 

    openssl x509 -text < /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1/fullchain.pem  | grep 'DNS:' | sed 's/\s*DNS:\([a-z0-9.\-]*\)[,\s]\?/\1 /g'

    > domain1 domain3

Answer (score 2):

## Use [Greenlock](https://git.rootprojects.org/root/greenlock.js) v2.7+

All of the code related to certificate generation and domain name and altname association has been updated.

Now when you change the domains array to include more domains it handles them individually rather than as a group.

Also, the information about the certificate is read directly from the certificate, so there can't be a mismatch between the "cache" and "the truth".

If you encounter further issues, please let us know directly:

- https://git.rootprojects.org/root/greenlock.js/issues